# AssertionError: python threading

Tags: python

I got this error and can't figure out where it went wrong.  I haven't done threading in python before.

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __int__(self,ip,port,socket):
        threading.Thread.__int__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket
        print "New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):
    ....
    ....


(clientsock, (ip,port)) = serverSocket.accept()

# Create new thread
newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,clientsock)
....
....
```

This is the error I got.

```
newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,clientsock)
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `__init__`. Also I'd recommend using new style inheritance.

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, ip, port, socket):
        super(ClientThread, self).__init__()
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket
        print "New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)
```